# Override CSS styles set for HTML tag

Tags: html, css

My page is referencing an CSS style sheet with the definition:

```
html {background-color:#FFFFFF;background-image:url('../images/Background.png');background-repeat:repeat-x; }
```

How do I overwrite the `background-image` element at the page level?  I need to overwrite the setting for just one page in my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a class to the html element and then use some inline styling to override the external stylesheet's styling.  You could also place the inline style in an external style sheet which would be best practice.

```
<html class="myHtmlTag">
   <head>
     <link href="externalStyle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
     html.myHtmlTag{
       background: none !important;
       background-image:none !important;
     }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Minus the space. (`html.myHtmlTag`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting only the `html` tag without any other selectors than you can simply include another `html` style AFTER the main css.   Per CSS specificity - they will only have the value of 1 tag each (no ids, no classes) - so the latter one will style the element.

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" /> 

<!-- anywhere from here down you can include a style to over ride html -->
```

Here's a quick demo:

```
html {background-color:#000;background-image:url('http://lxmpro.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/site-background-pattern-07.jpeg');background-repeat:repeat-x; }


/*  second reference to html tag overrides the first */
html {background-image:url('http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/wallpaper-pattern.jpg');}
```

Working Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/K68D3/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `!important` property on the `background` `background-image` style like so:

```
html{background-color:#000000 !important;background-image:url('your/image/path') !important;...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply a class to the body tag? IE:

```
<body class="home"> 
<body class="articlepage">
```

Otherwise, you technically could use jQuery, assuming you have access to drop code on the page to do the function but are locked out

```
<script>$("body").addClass("home");</script>
```

----or------

```
<script>$("body").addClass("articlepage");</script>
```

These allow you to do classes:

```
body.home {background-image:url(homebg.jpg);}
body.articlepage {background-image:url(articlebg.jpg);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic inline style override of class background color:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.city {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2 class="city" style="background-color: tomato;">London</h2>
<p>London is the capital of England.</p>

</body>
</html>
```